# kivy official pong tutorial: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to learn Kivy with [this tutorial](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html). I've copy pasted the code after "Here is the entire code for this step:" to main.py and main.kv as described. When trying to run, I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
   PongApp().run()
  File "/home/kivy/code/kivy/kivy/app.py", line 527, in run
   root = self.build()
  File "main.py", line 41, in build
   game.serve_ball()
  File "main.py", line 23, in serve_ball
   self.ball.center = self.center
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'
```

What am I doing wrong?

main.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size          

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
```

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        #bounce off top and bottom
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        #bounce off left and right
        if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

Comment: Looks like your `game` object doesn't have a member called `center`, but without code it's impossible to say much.

Comment: Please see the link. The whole code is there after "Here is the entire code for this step:"

Comment: what is your code? self seems like being `None`.

Comment: I added "from kivy.lang import Builder; Builder.load_file('main.kv')" to main.py and it works perfectly. Why "main.kv" was not detected automatically is still a mistery to me.

Comment: @Matt you should leave your own answer then. Might help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the wrong name for your KV file. It should be "pong.kv". If the name of the KV file matches the name of your app (minus App), then it will be automagically used.

You named your KV file "main.kv" which did not match with your app name "PongApp", so the magic did not happen. You were able to manually load the KV file by using Builder.load_file(). If you look back at the tutorial, you can see it requires you to name the KV file as "pong.kv".

Comment: And this is correct answer. I wrongly assumed that it is the name of .py and .kv that need to match. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`self.ball` is being initialized with:

```
ball = ObjectProperty(None)
```

This gives it a default value of `None`. Thus when you try to access `self.ball.center` it fails.

The tutorial contains a step that you probably missed:

> Don’t forget to hook it up in the kv file, by giving the child widget an id and setting the PongGame’s ball ObjectProperty to that id

Comment: Thank you, but this step is already contained in copy-pasted code. I included it in the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I've added

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('main.kv')
```

to my main.py and it works perfectly. Why "main.kv" was not detected automatically is still a mistery to me.